# GPU_FFT: in unmpamem: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, fft, gpu

This code being compiled along with the gpu_fft libraries throws this:

Error:

```
mailbox.c: In function 'unmapmem':
mailbox.c:77:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Using code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "mailbox.h"
#include "gpu_fft.h"

int main(){
    struct GPU_FFT *fft;
    int m, l, d, j, k, i;
    m = mbox_open();
    l = 8;           //length
    d = GPU_FFT_FWD;     //direction
    j = 500;         //jobs
    k = 255;         //loops
    float data[k];

    for (i=0; i<k; i++){
        data[i] = i*0.00247;
        printf("data[%d] = %f\n", i, data[i]);
        }

    float *dat;
    gpu_fft_prepare(m, l, d, j, &fft);  

    dat = &data[8];

    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
        fft = (struct GPU_FFT *) &dat;
        gpu_fft_execute(fft);
        printf("data[%d] = %f, out = %d\n", i, data[i], fft);
        }


    gpu_fft_release(fft);
    return 0;
}
```

First, I understand there are libraries included that I do not use here, they are for future use. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please post all of mailbox.c.  Specifically, what does the code around line 77 look like?

Comment: Mailbox.c is on this github page:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/hello_pi/hello_fft/mailbox.c

I double checked the line numbers are the same on the github as to the file I am using, and they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailbox.c file is not written properly.  Look at the function prototype for unmapmem().  It has a void* return type, but never returns anything!  It looks like the developer copy/pasted a function prototype from a previous function and forgot to delete the asterisk.  This is why the compiler warns you about line 77 in that file.

Edited to add: it appears that the developer never wanted to return anything from unmapmem().  You *should* be ok with just changing the return type to void (i.e., just delete the asterisk).

Also, be sure to contact the developer of the mailbox.c file about the bug.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a return statement.  For example, if your function needs to return an int.  Every place that you return from the function, use return nRetVal, where nRetVal is some integer value.  This includes the last line of the function.  Alternately you can declare your function as type void.

Comment: You know when I added my answer, there was no code.  So I couldn't look at the exact type he needed returned.